# Convex solution for elliptic PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations, reference-request

First, consider the equation :

\begin{equation}\tag{1}\label{osmx}
    \begin{cases}
     \Delta u(x) =  2n, \ \ x \in\Omega \\
      u(x)  = \|x\|^2, \ \ x \in \partial\Omega \\
    \end{cases}
  \end{equation}

where $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ is bounded and regular enough. Obviously the unique solution of (\ref{osmx}) is $u(x) = \|x\|^2$,  which is convex, and its convexity doesn't depend on the geometry of $\Omega$. Consider now the following equation:
  \begin{equation}\tag{2}\label{osmx2}
    \begin{cases}
     -\text{div}(a(x)\nabla u(x)) =  2n, \ \ x \in\Omega \\
      u(x)  = \|x\|^2, \ \ x \in \partial\Omega \\
    \end{cases}
  \end{equation}

where $a$ is defined as follow:
  \begin{equation}\label{eq:osmx3}
    a(x) =  \begin{cases}
     \ a_1, \ \ x \in\Omega_1 \\
     \ a_2, \ \ x \in\Omega_2 \\
    \end{cases}
  \end{equation}

Where $\Omega_1 \subset\Omega$ is open and $\Omega_2 = \Omega\setminus\overline\Omega_1$ and $a_1, a_2\in \mathbb{R}$. This problem is called **elliptic transmission problem**.  I have proved that if $a_1-a_2$ is small enough, the solution of (\ref{osmx2}) restricted to each $\Omega_i$ is convex. I did that using the **transmission conditions**, regular estimations, Sobolev inequalities and $C^2$ proximity of the solution with the solution of (\ref{osmx}). I never used geometry hypothesis, and I want to know if that problem (generalizations) is well known, or any idea to prove convexity, maybe with more flexible conditions on $a_i$.